# Header does not align with text frame

Tags: horizontal-alignment, header-footer, warnings

I have noticed that my header not is aligning with my text boarder, which I would like. The problem only occurs when I have the part where I adjust the spacing above and below equations. Can anybody tell me what to do to avoid the alignment problem?

I also have some issues with `Underfull \vbox` and `Overfull \hbox` warnings—maybe it is related to the problem. In any case, I would also like to get rid of them.

[image: Illustration of misalignment]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside]{memoir}

% Packages

\usepackage{layout}         % Layout frames
\usepackage{showframe}      % Layout frames

% Spacing around equations

\expandafter\def\expandafter\normalsize\expandafter{%
  \normalsize
  \setlength\abovedisplayskip{-1\parskip}
  \setlength\belowdisplayskip{0.5\parskip}
  \setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{-1\parskip}
  \setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{0.5\parskip}
}

% Header

\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{empty}

% Defining general header
\setlength{\headwidth}{\textwidth}
  \addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparsep}
  \addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparwidth}

\copypagestyle{thesis}{myheadings}            % Create pagestyle 'thesis'
\makerunningwidth{thesis}{\headwidth}
\makeheadrule{thesis}{\headwidth}{0.2pt}      % Horizontal line in header
\makeheadposition{thesis}{flushright}{flushleft}{}{}

\makepsmarks{thesis}{
  \nouppercaseheads
  \createmark{chapter}{left}{nonumber}{\@chapapp\ }{. \ }
  \createmark{section}{right}{nonumber}{}{} 
  \createplainmark{toc}{both}{\contentsname}
  \createplainmark{lof}{both}{\listfigurename}
  \createplainmark{lot}{both}{\listtablename}
  \createplainmark{bib}{both}{\bibname}
  \createplainmark{index}{both}{\indexname}
  \createplainmark{glossary}{both}{\glossaryname}
}

\makeevenhead{thesis}
  {\sffamily\bfseries\small\thepage}{}{\sffamily\bfseries\small\leftmark}

\makeoddhead{thesis}
  {\sffamily\bfseries\small\rightmark}{}{\sffamily\bfseries\small\thepage}

\pagestyle{thesis} % Activating pagestyle


\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}

\pagebreak

Some other text

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside]{memoir}

% Packages

\usepackage{layout}         % Layout frames
\usepackage{showframe}      % Layout frames

% Header

\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{empty}

% Defining general header
\setlength{\headwidth}{\textwidth}
\addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparsep}
\addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparwidth}

\copypagestyle{thesis}{myheadings}            % Create pagestyle 'thesis'
\makerunningwidth{thesis}{\headwidth}
\makeheadrule{thesis}{\headwidth}{0.2pt}      % Horizontal line in header
\makeheadposition{thesis}{flushright}{flushleft}{}{}

\makepsmarks{thesis}{
  \nouppercaseheads
  \createmark{chapter}{left}{nonumber}{\@chapapp\ }{. \ }
  \createmark{section}{right}{nonumber}{}{}
  \createplainmark{toc}{both}{\contentsname}
  \createplainmark{lof}{both}{\listfigurename}
  \createplainmark{lot}{both}{\listtablename}
  \createplainmark{bib}{both}{\bibname}
  \createplainmark{index}{both}{\indexname}
  \createplainmark{glossary}{both}{\glossaryname}
}

\makeevenhead{thesis}
{\sffamily\bfseries\small\thepage}{}{\sffamily\bfseries\small\leftmark}

\makeoddhead{thesis}
{\sffamily\bfseries\small\rightmark}{}{\sffamily\bfseries\small\thepage}

\pagestyle{thesis} % Activating pagestyle


\begin{document}

  \setlength\abovedisplayskip{-1\parskip}
  \setlength\belowdisplayskip{0.5\parskip}
  \setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{-1\parskip}
  \setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{0.5\parskip}


  \chapter{Test chapter}

  \pagebreak

  Some other text.
  \begin{equation}
    a + b = c
  \end{equation}
  Some more text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: That fixed the alignment problem, but I still get a badbox error on line 1. What does it mean when the badbox is referring to line 1 of the master document?

Comment: @Christoffer Your example has a page break which forces an essentially empty page. TeX complains that there is not enough stuff to fill the space (underfull vbox). I assume this is not the case in your actual document since it would be unusual to want an almost empty first page. At least, I think this is why and the warning goes away if I replace `\pagebreak` with `\clearpage`.

Comment: Thank you. Now I change my `\pagebreak`with `\clearpage`, and I see fewer of those badboxes. Lovely.